# "numrt": identifyer not found despite of defining that function

Tags: c++

I'm writing a library of mathematical functions in C++. I made the sqrt function and it works well. I also tried to make a root function that counts n'th root of a number. I have 3 files - emath.cpp, emath.hpp, main.cpp (emath is name of my library).

emath.cpp:

```
namespace emath
    {
    class emath
        {
        public:
           /* ... */
        //Returns value of square root of a number.
        static double sqrt(double tur);

        //Rerurns value of a root of a number.
        static double numrt(int stopien, double tur);
    };
}
```

emath.hpp:

```
#ifndef EMATH_HPP
#define EMATH_HPP

using namespace std;

namespace emath
    {
    class emath
        {
        public:
        /* ... */

        int emath::derivative(double x)
        {
              return 0;
        }
        //****************************************************************
        double emath::derivative(double number, int pow)
        {
              double result = 1;
              for (int i = 1; i < pow; i++)
              {
                    result *= number;
              }
              result *= pow;
              return result;
         }
        //************************************************************************
        double emath::derivative(double number, int pow, double numbey)
        {
             return ((derivative(number, pow) + derivative(numbey)));
        }

        //************************************************************************
        double emath::sqrt(double tur)          //This function
        {
    int a;

    static int i = 0;
    for (; i * i <= tur; i++)
    {

    }
    if (i * i == tur)
    {
        return i;
    }
    a = i;
    return sqrtl(a);
}
//************************************************************************
double emath::numrt(int stopien, double tur)          //This function
{
    int a;

    static int i = 0;
    for (; i * i <= tur; i++)
    {

    }
    if (i * i == tur)
    {
        return i;
    }
    a = i;
    static int mul = 1;
    for (int p = 0; p < stopien; p++)
    {
        mul *= i;
    }

    return numrtel(mul, i, a);
}






private:
//****************************************************************
double emath::sqrtel(double tur, static int k = 0)  //Implementation of Newton's Method
{
    double a;                                                      //Creates a - our xn.
    if (k == 1000000)
    {
        return a;
    }
    a = a - ((a * a - tur) / derivative(a, 2, - tur));          //Proper implementation os Newton's Method
    ++k;                                                        //k is counter
    return sqrtel(a);
}
//***************************************************************
double emath::numrtel(int mul, int i, double tur, static int k = 0)
{
    double a;                                                      //Creates a - our xn.
    if (k == 1000000)
    {
        return a;
    }
    a = a - ((mul - tur) / derivative(a, i, - tur));          //Proper implementation os Newton's Method
    ++k;                                                        //k is counter
    return numrtel(mul, i, a);
}
};  //end of class
}   //end of namespace

#endif // EMATH_HPP
```

If my main.cpp is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "emath.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace emath;

int main()
{
    double number;
    cin >> number;

    cout << sqrt(number);

}
```

it works very well, but if main.cpp is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "emath.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace emath;

int main()
{
    double number;
    cin >> number;

    cout << numrt(3, number);

}
```

I get a compiler error: "numrt": identifyer not found.
I'm using MS VS Studio 2012 Compiler with Qt Creator.
Why is that?

Comment: Do you tried to call with emath::numrt(3, number)?

Comment: Your .hpp declares `numrt` to be non-static, meaning that you need to call it on a `emath` instance.  Or make the function static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declared `numrt()` inside a class `emath`, you have to state that class name in the function call:

```
emath::numrt()
```

(The full call, including the namespace name is `emath::emath::numrt()`.)

I wonder why the call to `sqrt()` works, since for your code to execute, you'd have to call it with `emath::sqrt()` as well. Are you sure that **your** code is executed and not some code from standard libraries?

Comment: Yes, now it works - thanks to you I realized that my function doesn't retur good value :/ Thank you :-)